# get startdate and enddate for current quarter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I am trying to set a start date and end date by the quarter.

For example, I am working on a reporting system where i need to report data for quarter 1, quarter 2, quarter 3, and quarter 4.

Quarter One - January - March

Quarter Two - April - June

Quarter Three - July - September

Quarter Four - October - December

I have for example some cases for the current month, and the previous month as shown below.

```
   case 'this_month':
      $start_date = date(DATE_FORMAT, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), 1, date("Y")));
      $end_date = date(DATE_FORMAT, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
    break;
    case 'last_month':
      $start_date = date(DATE_FORMAT, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 1, 1, date("Y")));
      $end_date = date(DATE_FORMAT, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), 0, date("Y")));
    break;
```

But now i need to add cases for **this and last quarter** and I am not sure how to actually do that so it reflects the proper quarter range.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Since I couldn't find any smooth solution, I just submitted a feature request for PHP to natively support realtive formats like `new \DateTime('first day of last quarter')`: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76622

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check this for `this quarter`.

```
 case 'this_quarter':

          $current_month = date('m');
          $current_year = date('Y');
          if($current_month>=1 && $current_month<=3)
          {
            $start_date = strtotime('1-January-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-Januray 12:00:00 AM
            $end_date = strtotime('1-April-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-April 12:00:00 AM means end of 31 March
          }
          else  if($current_month>=4 && $current_month<=6)
          {
            $start_date = strtotime('1-April-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-April 12:00:00 AM
            $end_date = strtotime('1-July-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-July 12:00:00 AM means end of 30 June
          }
          else  if($current_month>=7 && $current_month<=9)
          {
            $start_date = strtotime('1-July-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-July 12:00:00 AM
            $end_date = strtotime('1-October-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-October 12:00:00 AM means end of 30 September
          }
          else  if($current_month>=10 && $current_month<=12)
          {
            $start_date = strtotime('1-October-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-October 12:00:00 AM
            $end_date = strtotime('1-January-'.($current_year+1));  // timestamp or 1-January Next year 12:00:00 AM means end of 31 December this year
          }



        break;
```

**Update : 2**
and for `last quarter`

```
case 'last_quarter':

          $current_month = date('m');
          $current_year = date('Y');

          if($current_month>=1 && $current_month<=3)
          {
            $start_date = strtotime('1-October-'.($current_year-1));  // timestamp or 1-October Last Year 12:00:00 AM
            $end_date = strtotime('1-January-'.$current_year);  // // timestamp or 1-January  12:00:00 AM means end of 31 December Last year
          } 
          else if($current_month>=4 && $current_month<=6)
          {
            $start_date = strtotime('1-January-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-Januray 12:00:00 AM
            $end_date = strtotime('1-April-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-April 12:00:00 AM means end of 31 March
          }
          else  if($current_month>=7 && $current_month<=9)
          {
            $start_date = strtotime('1-April-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-April 12:00:00 AM
            $end_date = strtotime('1-July-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-July 12:00:00 AM means end of 30 June
          }
          else  if($current_month>=10 && $current_month<=12)
          {
            $start_date = strtotime('1-July-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-July 12:00:00 AM
            $end_date = strtotime('1-October-'.$current_year);  // timestamp or 1-October 12:00:00 AM means end of 30 September
          }



        break;
```

Comment: This solution mostly correct. Its needed to minus 1 second from end_date. At bottom: `$end_date=$end_date-1`

Answer (score 25):

```
/**
* Compute the start and end date of some fixed o relative quarter in a specific year.
* @param mixed $quarter  Integer from 1 to 4 or relative string value:
*                        'this', 'current', 'previous', 'first' or 'last'.
*                        'this' is equivalent to 'current'. Any other value
*                        will be ignored and instead current quarter will be used.
*                        Default value 'current'. Particulary, 'previous' value
*                        only make sense with current year so if you use it with
*                        other year like: get_dates_of_quarter('previous', 1990)
*                        the year will be ignored and instead the current year
*                        will be used.
* @param int $year       Year of the quarter. Any wrong value will be ignored and
*                        instead the current year will be used.
*                        Default value null (current year).
* @param string $format  String to format returned dates
* @return array          Array with two elements (keys): start and end date.
*/
public static function get_dates_of_quarter($quarter = 'current', $year = null, $format = null)
{
    if ( !is_int($year) ) {        
       $year = (new DateTime)->format('Y');
    }
    $current_quarter = ceil((new DateTime)->format('n') / 3);
    switch (  strtolower($quarter) ) {
    case 'this':
    case 'current':
       $quarter = ceil((new DateTime)->format('n') / 3);
       break;

    case 'previous':
       $year = (new DateTime)->format('Y');
       if ($current_quarter == 1) {
          $quarter = 4;
          $year--;
        } else {
          $quarter =  $current_quarter - 1;
        }
        break;

    case 'first':
        $quarter = 1;
        break;

    case 'last':
        $quarter = 4;
        break;

    default:
        $quarter = (!is_int($quarter) || $quarter < 1 || $quarter > 4) ? $current_quarter : $quarter;
        break;
    }
    if ( $quarter === 'this' ) {
        $quarter = ceil((new DateTime)->format('n') / 3);
    }
    $start = new DateTime($year.'-'.(3*$quarter-2).'-1 00:00:00');
    $end = new DateTime($year.'-'.(3*$quarter).'-'.($quarter == 1 || $quarter == 4 ? 31 : 30) .' 23:59:59');

    return array(
        'start' => $format ? $start->format($format) : $start,
        'end' => $format ? $end->format($format) : $end,
    );
}
```

I develop this function to deal with quarter in any way: relative (this, previous, first, last) and fixed.

Examples:

```
get_dates_of_quarter();
//return current quarter start and end dates

get_dates_of_quarter(2);
//return 2nd quarter start and end dates of current year

get_dates_of_quarter('first', 2010, 'Y-m-d');
//return start='2010-01-01' and end='2014-03-31'

get_dates_of_quarter('current', 2009, 'Y-m-d');
//Supposing today is '2014-08-22' (3rd quarter), this will return
//3rd quarter but of year 2009.
//return start='2009-07-01' and end='2009-09-30'

get_dates_of_quarter('previous');
//Supposing today is '2014-02-18' (1st quarter), this will return
//return start='2013-10-01' and end='2013-12-31'
```

Waiting this help someone ;)

Comment: @Delmo please check for Feb month having 28 days.. it gives wrong values

Answer (score 24):

Simple code:

```
$current_quarter = ceil(date('n') / 3);
$first_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y') . '-' . (($current_quarter * 3) - 2) . '-1'));
$last_date = date('Y-m-t', strtotime(date('Y') . '-' . (($current_quarter * 3)) . '-1'));
```

Comment: This is wrong as well-  the "last date" is not the first of a month... should be the last day of that month...

Comment: @Scott you may not have seen the "t" of 'Y-m-t', the answer is correct!

Comment: beautiful answer in a sea of noise

Answer (score 15):

what about:

```
$offset = (date('n')%3)-1; // modulo ftw
$start = new DateTime("first day of -$offset month midnight");
$offset = 3-(date('n')%3); // modulo ftw again
$end = new DateTime("last day of +$offset month midnight");
```

Comment: Stunned someone has a one liner for that big block of code above ;)
`"first day of -" . ((date('n')%3)-1) . " month midnight"`

Comment: Tried this today - 3/9/19 - but doesn't work - the first offset is -1 and the string is --1... I got 4/1/19 as the start - should have been 1/1/19 - KLOZ below looks right

Comment: start will be incorrect in the last months of a quarter because %3 will give 0. Your offset (`(date('n')%3-1`) will give jan = 1-1 = 0, feb = 2-1 = 1, march = 0-1 = -1 etc. instead you can use `(date('n')-1)%3` which will give jan = 0%3 = 0, feb = 1%3 = 1, mar = 2%3 = 2, apr = 3%3 = 0, etc.
additionally, for the last months your offset (`3-(date('n')%3)`) will be +3 which is too high: jan = 3-1 = 2, feb = 3-2 = 1, mar = 3-0 = 3, apr = 3-1 = 2. You can resolve this by re-applying modulo: `(3-(date('n'))%3)%3`, jan = 2%3 = 2, feb = 1%3 = 1, mar = 3%3 = 0, apr = 2%3 = 2.

Comment: first offset should be:
`$offset = (date('n')-1)%3;`
second should be:
`$offset = (3-(date('n'))%3)%3;`

Answer (score 7):

Some answers are way too complicated IMO

```
public function getStartOfQuarter()
{
     return date(sprintf('Y-%s-01', floor((date('n') - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1));
}

public function getEndOfQuarter()
{
    return date(sprintf('Y-%s-t', floor((date('n') + 2) / 3) * 3));
}
```

Comment: Buggy? Gives `2016-9-01` and `2016-9-30` for `time() = 1473937773`

Comment: Fixed. I had a unit test that: 1. was wrong; 2. wasn't even run.

Comment: First return statement should have two additional closing brackets before semicolon.

Comment: This returns 2021-12-30 as the last day of this quarter.  There are 31 days in December..

Comment: and idea how to to the same but for previous quarter?

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to point [SynaTree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126269/2118764)'s solution doesn't work for every last 3rd month in quarter.

Here's a modified solution using DateTime.

```php
$now = new DateTimeImmutable();
$offset = ($now->format('n') - 1) % 3;
$start = $now->modify("first day of -{$offset} month midnight");
$endExcluded = $start->modify("+3 month");
$endIncluded = $start->modify("+3 month -1 second");
```

`$endExcluded` works well when for DatePeriod loops, where the end date is excluded when time is 00:00:00.

Answer (score 3):

A versatile version would be:

```
    $date = new DateTime(/* you may insert a date here, else its now */);
    //$date->modify('-3 months'); // you may want last quarter or any other modifcation
    $quarter = ceil($date->format('n')/3);

    $start = new DateTime();
    $start->setDate($date->format('Y'), (($quarter*3)-2), 1)->setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);

    $end = new DateTime();
    $end->setDate($date->format('Y'), ($quarter*3), 1);
    $end->setDate($date->format('Y'), ($quarter*3), $end->format('t'))->setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);

    echo $start->format('Y-m-d');
    echo $end->format('Y-m-d');
```

this is simple yet effective. It let's you choose the input date and make relative adaptions with modify.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a whole lot simpler I think.

```
function get_this_quarter() {
    $current_month = date('m');
    $current_quarter_start = ceil($current_month/4)*3+1; // get the starting month of the current quarter
    $start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, $current_quarter_start, 1, date('Y') ));
    $end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, $current_quarter_start+3, 1, date('Y') ));
    // by adding or subtracting from $current_quarter_start within the mktime function you can get any quarter of any year you want.
    return array($start_date, $end_date);
}
```

This works just as good without all the if statements and is much more flexible. As mentioned in the comments within the code, you can easily modify the $current_quarter_variable to suit your needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can the "end date" be the first of a month?!
And how can the end date of the quarter for the given date "25.03.2016" be the "01.07.2016" while it should be the 31.05.2016?

THIS DOES NOT WORK

Answer (score 2):

```
$monthsFromStart = (date('n') - 1) % 3; // 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...
$monthsToEnd = 2 - $monthsFromStart; // 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, ...

$startDay = new DateTime("first day of -$monthsFromStart month midnight");
$endDay = new DateTime("last day of +$monthsToEnd month midnight");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) function. For your example, is look like:

```
case 'this_month':
    $start_date = new DateTime('first day of this month');
    $end_date = new DateTime('last day of this month');
break;
case 'last_month':
    $start_date = new DateTime('first day of next month');
    $end_date = new DateTime('last day of next month');
break;

echo $start_date->format(DATE_FORMAT);
echo $end_date->format(DATE_FORMAT);
```

And if you want to get the first and last days of quarter, try to use:

```
 $start_date = new DateTime('first day of January');
 $end_date = new DateTime('last day of March');

 echo $start_date->format(DATE_FORMAT);
 echo $end_date->format(DATE_FORMAT);
```

Or use function [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php). Example with strtotime:

```
$quarter_start = strtotime('first day of January');
$quarter_end = strtotime('last day of March');

echo date(DATE_FORMAT, $quarter_start);
echo date(DATE_FORMAT, $quarter_end);
```

Comment: Time changes, and January and March are no longer valid

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```php
define('DATE_FORMAT', 'Y-m-d');

function get_start_and_end_date($case) {
    $start = 'first day of ';
    $end = 'last day of ';

    if ($case == 'this_quarter') {
        $case = 'quarter_' . ceil((new DateTime)->format('n') / 3);
    }

    switch ($case) {
        case 'prev_month'    : $start .= 'previous month'; $end .= 'previous month'; break;
        default              :
        case 'this_month'    : $start .= 'this month';     $end .= 'this month';     break;
        case 'next_month'    : $start .= 'next month';     $end .= 'next month';     break;
        case 'first_quarter' :
        case 'quarter_1'     : $start .= 'January';        $end .= 'March';          break;
        case 'quarter_2'     : $start .= 'April';          $end .= 'June';           break;
        case 'quarter_3'     : $start .= 'July';           $end .= 'September';      break;
        case 'last_quarter'  :
        case 'quarter_4'     : $start .= 'October';        $end .= 'December';       break;
    }

    return [
        'start' => (new DateTime($start))->format(DATE_FORMAT),
        'end' => (new DateTime($end))->format(DATE_FORMAT),
    ];
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/91057)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDates( $passedDate = '' ) {
    if( $passedDate == '' ) {
        $v = ceil( date( "m" ) / 3 );
        $y = date( "Y" );
    } else {
        $v = ceil( $month / 3 );
        $y = date( "Y", strtotime( $passedDate ) );
    }
    $y = date( "Y" );
    $m = ( $v * 3 ) - 2;
    $date = $y . '-' . $m . '-' . 01;
    $return['begin'] = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime(  $date ) );
    $return['end'] = date( "Y-m-t", strtotime( $return['begin'] . "+ 2 months"  ) );
    $return['version'] = $y . 'Q' . ceil( date( "m" ) / 4 );
    return $return;
}
```

This Function will return starting and end date and quarter for current date by default, however if you want it for particular date just pass month to it.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to get the start/end of the current quarter in dates:

```
$qtr_start = date("Y-".(ceil(date("n")/3))."-01");
```

Then, just add 3 months in the correct place to get the end:

```
$qtr_end = date("Y-".(ceil(date("n")/3)+3)."-01");
```

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution.

```
function getCurrentQuarter($timestamp=false){
    if(!$timestamp)$timestamp=time();
    $day = date('n', $timestamp);
    $quarter = ceil($day/3);
    return $quarter;
}

function getPreviousQuarter($timestamp=false){
    if(!$timestamp)$timestamp=time();
    $quarter = getCurrentQuarter($timestamp) - 1;
    if($quarter < 0){
        $quarter = 4;
    }
    return $quarter;
}

function getNextQuarter($timestamp=false){
    if(!$timestamp)$timestamp=time();
    $quarter = getCurrentQuarter($timestamp) + 1;
    if($quarter > 4){
        $quarter = 0;
    }
    return $quarter;
}

function getFirstAndLastDayOfQuarter($quarter, $year=false){
    if(!$year)$year=date('Y');
    $startDate = new DateTime($year.'-'.($quarter*3-2).'-1');
    //Get first day of first month of next quarter
    $endMonth = $quarter*3+1;
    if($endMonth>12){
        $endMonth = 1;
        $year++;
    }
    $endDate = new DateTime($year.'-'.$endMonth.'-1');
    //Subtract 1 second to get last day of prior month
    $endDate->sub(new DateInterval('PT1S'));
    return array($startDate, $endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply this greatly using basic math.

Each Month number minus 1 % 3 will tell how many months you are offset from the current quarter..

```
/**
 * @param DateTime $date
 * @return array
 */
function getQuarterRangeFromDate(DateTime $date)
{

    // Clone the date to avoid modifying your date in current context
    $quarter_start = clone($date);

    // Find the offset of months
    $months_offset = ($date->format('m') - 1) % 3;


    // Modify quarter date
    $quarter_start->modify(" - " . $months_offset . " month")
        ->modify("first day of this month");


    $quarter_end = clone($quarter_start);
    $quarter_end->modify("+ 3 month");

    return [$quarter_start, $quarter_end];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I glimpsed over answers and all are about quarters of this year.
Sometimes, you need quarter for particular date.
Here is my attempt with detailed explanation what-does-what in code comments:

```
/**
     * get quarter begin/end date
     * 
     * possible usage:
     * quarter start date: quarter('2016-04-12')[start] - result: 2016-04-01
     * quarter end date: quarter('2016-04-12')[end] - result: 2016-06-30
     * quarter number: quarter('2016-04-12')[number] - result: 2
     * 
     * @param  string   $time   date you want quarter begin and end for - accepted formats, at least: 'Y-m', but also: 'Y-m-d', 'Y-m-d H:i:s' etc.
     * @return array    [quarter start, quarter end, quarter number]
     */
    public function quarter($time)
    {
        /**
         * get quarter number for given date
         * we are ceiling floating point value, so I use (int) casting to get just integer (without decimal part)
         * round() could be used instead of casting to (int)
         */
        $quarter = (int)ceil(date("m", strtotime($time)) / 3);
        $year = date("Y", strtotime($time));

        $quarters = [
            1 => ['01-01', '03-31', 1],
            2 => ['04-01', '06-30', 2],
            3 => ['07-01', '09-30', 3],
            4 => ['10-01', '12-31', 4],
        ];

        $quarterStart = $year . '-' . $quarters[$quarter][0];
        $quarterEnd = $year . '-' . $quarters[$quarter][1];
        $quarterNumber = $quarters[$quarter][2];

        return ['start' => $quarterStart, 'end' => $quarterEnd, 'number' => $quarterNumber];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed some function to give me dates for each quarter so I could fetch some sales info. Here is the code if anyone needs it:

```
   private function getQuarterRange($quarter, $year=null) {
        if ($quarter > 4 || $quarter < 1)
            return null;

        if ($year == null)
            $year = date('Y');


        $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year . '-' . (($quarter * 3) - 2). '-1'));
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate)) . '+3 month - 1 day'));
        return ['startDate' => $startDate, 'endDate' => $endDate];
    }
```

Simply call: `var_dump($this->getQuarterRange(4, 2018));`
Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["startDate"]=>
  string(10) "2018-10-01"
  ["endDate"]=>
  string(10) "2018-12-31"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is so difficult - several solutions were really close here but were failing to find the FIRST and LAST day of a quarter. Quarters don't end on the first!

Modified from KLOZ above:

```
    $current_quarter = ceil(date('n') / 3);
    $first_day_of_this_quarter = date('m/d/Y', strtotime(date('Y').'-'.(($current_quarter*3)-2).'-01'));
    $last_day_of_this_quarter = date('m/d/Y', strtotime(date('Y').'-'.($current_quarter*3).'-'.(date("t",strtotime(date('Y').'-'.($current_quarter*3).'-01')))));
```

Comment: KLOZ's answer works correctly for me.  This errors, however:  TypeError
date(): Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int, string given

Comment: I just fixed my code-  was missing a strtotime() after the date("t") - tested thoroughly - this is the answer to the OP :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$QuarterMonth = ["1" => ["Y-01-01","Y-03-31"],"2"=>["Y-04-01","Y-06-30"],"3"=>["Y-07-01","Y-09-30"],"4"=>["Y-10-01","Y-12-31"]];
$curMonth = date("m", time());

$qtr_month_from = date($QuarterMonth[ceil($curMonth/3)][0]);
$qtr_month_to = date($QuarterMonth[ceil($curMonth/3)][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below we can get the start date of the current quarter.

```php
$intCurrentMonth               = date( 'n' );
$fltCurrentQuarter             = ( $intCurrentMonth - 1 ) / 3;
$intCurrentQuarter             = ( int ) $fltCurrentQuarter;
$fltCurrentQuarterMantissa     = $fltCurrentQuarter - $intCurrentQuarter;
$fltCurrentQuarterMantissa     = ( int ) ( $fltCurrentQuarterMantissa * 100 ) / 100;
$intFirstMonthOfCurrentQuarter = $intCurrentMonth - ceil( $fltCurrentQuarterMantissa * 3 );
$strFirstDateOfCurrentQuarter  = date( 'm/d/Y', strtotime( $intFirstMonthOfCurrentQuarter . '/01' ) );
```

There is good scope to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on an older PHP version :

```
$current_quarter = ceil(date('n') / 3);
$first_day_of_this_quarter = date('m/d/Y', strtotime(date('Y').'-'.(($current_quarter*3)-2).'-1'));
$last_day_of_this_quarter = date('m/d/Y', strtotime(date('Y').'-'.($current_quarter*3).'-'.(date("t",strtotime(date('Y').'-'.($current_quarter*3).'-1')))));
```