# Range check of a quarter and year?

Tags: php, arrays

I am kind of stuck on figuring out how to do this.

In my array that I am looping over, it has multiple arrays with the following fields `year` and `quarter`. Year is in numeric form like `2012` and quarter is in text form like `Q1` or `Q2`

Now I am given a range for example

from: `Q1 2013` to: `Q3 2014`

I have access  to the numeric form of the quarters in the range.

So this is the variables I have from the example above: `$quarter_from`, `$quarter_to`, `$year_from`, and `$year_to`

I need to figure out if the current array in the loop that has the fields `year` and `quarter` is in the range of the range given.

How do I go about checking? Sure I can do a simple numeric check for `years` but quarters is a whole another story. For example the current array could have `Q4` and `2013` and that's obviously in the range of the example, and the first case would pass by doing a year check. But for quarter, how do I check that?

Comment: maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185924/get-startdate-and-enddate-for-current-quarter-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do a concatenate of the quarter and year like this, assuming that the range that is selected logically makes sense (to comes later than from with respect to time).

from: `20122` => `year 2012 and quarter 2`

to: `20141` => `year 2014 and quarter 1`

So even though your quarter's value is in `to` is less than the quarter's value in `from` you still get a higher value in `to` because of the year.

This way you can now do a range check like this, by concatenating your `year` and `quarter` fields (do a `substr()` to get the second character of the string and convert to number then concatenate).

For example if `2013`, `Q4` shows up.

That looks like `20134` then do a range check like this

`20122 <= 20134 <= 20141` which should work.

Comment: Since this was the quickest and only needs a few lines of code to implement. I'll go with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this in a hurry, it's more of a phsudo code but should give you some idea:

```
From: Q2 2013
Middle: Q1 2014 (checking if in range of From and To)
To: Q1 2014
```

Now we need to compare the years of from and middle and middle and to, and if the year is the same in either case you can split the quarter to get the number of the quarter and compare the quarters to see if the middle part is actually in the range.

```
fromQuarter = from.quarter.split("")[1] // Q2 => 2
middleQuarter = middle.quarter.split("")[1] // Q1 => 1
toQuarter = to.quarter.split("")[1] // Q1 => 1

If to.year >= middle.year && middle.year >= from.year
    // Year range legit.
    if(to.year == middle.year || from.year == middle.year)
        // We need to check the quarters.
        if(to.year == middle.year)
            // Need to compare the quarter of the to year and the middle year.
            if(toQuarter >= middleQuarter )
                // In range.
            else
                // Out of range.
        if(from.year == middle.year)
            // Need to compare the quarter of the from year and the middle year.
            if(fromQuarter  <= middleQuarter)
                // In range.
            else
                // Out of range.
    else
        // Between two distinct years, in range.
else
    // Not in range.
```

I'll check this again soon to see if I made an logic error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function expand($quarter, $year) {
    return $year * 4 + $quarter;
}

$quarter_from = 1; $year_from = 2013;
$quarter_to = 3; $year_to = 2014;
$quarter = 3; $year = 2014;

$n1 = expand($quarter_from, $year_from);
$n2 = expand($quarter_to, $year_to);
$n = expand($quarter, $year);
$is_in_range = $n >= $n1 && $n <= $n2;
```