# how to set strtotime() into quarterly?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

how can i used `strtotime()` to get `'Current Quarter'` and `'Last Quarter'`?

I have this code to get the current and previous week:

```
// this week
$dayweekfrom = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("this week", strtotime($today_year.'-'.$today_month.'-'.$today_day)));
$dayweekTo = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("+6 day", strtotime($dayweekfrom)));
//last week
$lastweekfrom = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("last week", strtotime($today_year.'-'.$today_month.'-'.$today_day)));
$lastweekTo = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("+6 day", strtotime($lastweekfrom)));
```

I also want this to get the date of quarter from and to...

any idea about this?

Comment: Completely loss with your question

Comment: Have you seen [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185924/get-startdate-and-enddate-for-current-quarter-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185924/get-startdate-and-enddate-for-current-quarter-php)?

Comment: the answer I got is in here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185924/get-startdate-and-enddate-for-current-quarter-php thanks Kausha Mehta