# How to get timestamp of: current year quarter start/end, last quarter start/end, from specified date in PHP

Tags: php, date, timestamp

Is there any libraries or ready to use functions for easy calculating timestamps in PHP?

I need to get:

1. unixtimestamp: first second of current quarter,
2. unixtimestamp: last second of current quarter,
3. unixtimestamp: first second of previous quarter,
4. unixtimestamp: last second of previous quarter,

Problems:

- timezones,
- begining of the year in example 3) and 4)

How do You calculate that?
My code looks very complicated...

Comment: `\DateTime` - https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php. It can everything. Create a new date by f.e. `2021-01-01 00:00:00` or `today - 4 days midnight + 2 hours`, convert to another time zone, `->modify('today - 4 days midnight + 2 hours')`, convert to timestamp, done.

Comment: See here for lots of possible ways to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126269/3411766

Comment: @Mario did any of answers helped you?

Comment: @cottton do \DataTime support quarters like last quarter, this/current quarter, next quarter? I tried to find this in link You pasted with no results.

Comment: @MarioBash Not for quarters. But you just calculate a bit to get those dates. Search f.e. for "php datetime get first day of this quarter". See f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185924/get-startdate-and-enddate-for-current-quarter-php

Comment: @MarioBash BTW; here you can find relative formats like "this day noon" https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: @MarioBash please accept one of the answers you've got, it's good habit here
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Martin ok sorry I am new to Stack - thanks for advice :)

Comment: @MarioBash no worries... now I am sad my solution (answer) wasn't accepted :-[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function for you.

```
function getTimestampFromQuarter(string $quarterName = 'current', string $returnTimestamp = 'start', string $timezone = 'UTC', int $year = null): int {

    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));


    // if year not defined, we use current year
    $year = $year ?? date('Y');

    // current month
    $month = date("n");

    // current quarter number
    $quarter = ceil($month / 3);

    // we are looking for previous quarter
    if (in_array(strtolower($quarterName), ['previous','last'])) {
        $quarter--;
        if (0 == $quarter) {
            $quarter = 4;
            $year--;
        }
    }

    // we are looking for next quarter
    elseif (in_array(strtolower($quarterName), ['next'])) {
        $quarter++;
        if (4 == $quarter) {
            $quarter = 1;
            $year++;
        }
    }

    $quarterFirstMonth = (12 / 4) * ($quarter - 1) + 1; // first month of quarter
    $quarterLastMonth = (12 / 4) * ($quarter - 1) + 3; // last month of quarter


    if ('start'==$returnTimestamp) {
        $dt->setDate($year, $quarterFirstMonth, 1);
        $dt->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    }
    elseif ('end'==$returnTimestamp) {

        // looking for month days count
        $ts = new DateTime();
        $ts->setDate($year, $quarterLastMonth, 1);
        $ts->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
        $day = date('t', $ts->getTimestamp());
        unset($ts);


        $dt->setDate($year, $quarterLastMonth, $day);
        $dt->setTime(23, 59, 59);
    }

    return $dt->getTimestamp();
}
```

**Usage is easy:**

1.. first second of current quarter:

```
echo getTimestampFromQuarter('current', 'start');
// output: 1633046400 (equals to Friday 1. October 2021 0:00:00)
```

2.. last second of current quarter:

```
echo getTimestampFromQuarter('current', 'end'); 
// output: 1640995199 (equals to Friday 31. December 2021 23:59:59)
```

3.. first second of previous quarter:

```
echo getTimestampFromQuarter('previous', 'start'); 
// output: 1625097600 (equals to Thursday 1. July 2021 0:00:00)
```

4.. last second of previous quarter:

```
echo getTimestampFromQuarter('previous', 'end'); 
// output: 1633046399 (equals to Thursday 30. September 2021 23:59:59)
```

5.. first second of next quarter:

```
echo getTimestampFromQuarter('next', 'start'); 
// output: 1640995200 (equals to Saturday 1. January 2022 0:00:00)
```

6.. last second of next quarter:

```
echo getTimestampFromQuarter('next', 'end'); 
// output: 1648771199 (equals to Thursday 31. March 2022 23:59:59)
```

Comment: Good pice of code - much more simple that I did. You should expand this function to support 'next' as value of first parameter.

That would be enough:

`if (in_array(strtolower($quarterName), ['next'])) {
    $quarter++;
    if (5 == $quarter) {
      $quarter = 1;
      $year++;
    }
}`

Comment: @MarioBash OK, done, I've added "next quarter" functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I added a 3rd argument so as to make it possible to call the function from anywhere in - the part supported by timestamp - time. The 1st argument should now support numeric values(offsets), so that 'previous' and -1 should give the same result.

Apart from that.. It's probably easiest to check the block of test cases at the bottom of my answer.

```
function getQuarterTimestamp(string $quarter, string $timeOfDay, int $timestamp = null) : int {
    $timestamp = $timestamp ?? time();
    if ($timestamp < 0) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Bad timestamp argument");
    }

    // Offset to start of current quarter
    $currentMonthQuarterOffset = - (date('n', $timestamp) + 2) % 3;

    switch($quarter) {
        case 'next':
            $currentMonthQuarterOffset += 3; // Move forward 1 quarter
            break;
        case 'current':
            break;
        case 'previous':
            $currentMonthQuarterOffset -= 3; // Move back 1 quarter
            break;
        case is_numeric($quarter):
            $currentMonthQuarterOffset += 3*$quarter; // Move the number of quarters in $quarters
            break;
        default:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Bad quarter argument");
            break;
    }

    switch($timeOfDay) {
        case 'start':
            $dayOffset = 'first';
            $timeOffset = '00:00:00';
            break;
        case 'end':
            $currentMonthQuarterOffset += 2; // Default is start, move to end of quarter
            $dayOffset = 'last';
            $timeOffset = '23:59:59';
            break;
        default:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Bad timeOfDay argument");
            break;
    }

    $dateTimeStr = "{$dayOffset} day of {$currentMonthQuarterOffset} month ".date('Y-m-d', $timestamp)." {$timeOffset}";

    return (new DateTime($dateTimeStr))->getTimeStamp();
}
```

..and here's some code for testing(Comments are outputs after running on the 28th of Nov -21):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('previous', 'start')); // 2021-07-01 00:00:00
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('previous', 'end')); // 2021-09-30 23:59:59
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('current', 'start')); // 2021-10-01 00:00:00
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('current', 'end')); // 2021-12-31 23:59:59
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('next', 'start')); // 2022-01-01 00:00:00
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('next', 'end')); // 2022-03-31 23:59:59

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('previous', 'start', strtotime('2021-01-23 01:01:01'))); // 2020-10-01 00:00:00
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('previous', 'end', strtotime('2021-01-23 01:01:01'))); // 2020-12-31 23:59:59

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp(-4, 'start', strtotime('2021-01-23 01:01:01'))); // 2020-01-01 00:00:00
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp(-4, 'end', strtotime('2021-01-23 01:01:01'))); // 2020-03-31 23:59:59

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('current', 'start', strtotime('2021-01-23 01:01:01'))); // 2021-01-01 00:00:00
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s\n", getQuarterTimestamp('current', 'end', strtotime('2021-01-23 01:01:01'))); // 2021-03-31 23:59:59
```

**Note:** The `case is_numeric($quarter)` part works because of careful ordering of the `case` lines, and is technically not correct syntax, it could be better to move it outside the `switch`(and remove the default case with exception). If anyone wants me to I can write a version like that.

Comment: Did You tested: getQuarterTimestamp('previous', 'start'); in case when "curent" is in the first quarter of the year? Could You edit code and expand code to support for value "next" in $timestamp ?

Very clean code and easy to understand/debug.

Comment: @MarioBash Added 'next' and an argument ;)

Comment: I cannot accept both answers :(